# What is the time zone of a point at a border that separates two contiguous time zones?

Tags: timezone

What is the time zone of a point at a border that separates two contiguous time zones? For instance, in the image http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png, that is the time zone of a point that separates timezone zones +1 and +2? +1? +2? Both?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Are you asking what timezone a location that happens to be ON the border of the timezone "line" is?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your measurement error is greater than the width of an ideal line.

Answer (score 1):

Timezones, while primarily related to geography, are dictated by law according to the governing authority. India has a 10.5 hour offset from GMT not because the original architects of GMT intended half-hour offsets to be used but because the Indian government wanted it and, well, what are you going to do about it? Invade?

Applying that logic, the real question is: who owns the land?

There's no algorithm, no rule. It's not like a polygon rasterisation thing where pixels that fall exactly on the boundary of a piece of geometry are always assigned e.g. to the geometry on the right or below.

The logical conclusion is that individual points do no not have timezones because they have no area. Most points fall within a timezone. Not all do. Conversely, all areas have at least one timezone.